# weighted conditional expectation in adaboost

Tags: boosting, conditional-expectation

I'm looking at this paper,

http://www.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/AdditiveLogisticRegression/alr.pdf

around pages 10-11 (marked 346,347 in the pdf). This notation is introduced
$$
E_w[g(x,y)|x] := \frac{E[w(x,y)g(x,y)|x]}{E[w(x,y)|x]}
$$
where originally, we are attempting to minimize this:
$$
E[w(x,y)g(x,y;f,c)]
$$
with respect to f and c where
$w(x,y)=\exp(-yF(x))$, $g(x,y)=1-cf(x)+c^2/2$. Earlier, it was shown in minimizing $E[w(x,y; F(x))]$ with respect to F that it is sufficient to minimize the conditional, $E[w(x,y;F(x))|x]$.

Fine. This makes sense so far, but now in minimizing $E[w(x,y)g(x,y;f,c)]$ it seems as though we could take the same route and minimize $E[w(x,y)g(x,y;f,c) | x]$. This would be equivalent to $E_w$ without the denominator.

I see that scaling should not affect the minimum found since it does not involve $f$ or $c$. I also see that this scaling gives $E_w$ the usual linear expectation properties.

Is this introduced only for convenience or is there some other justification?